# Is there a Gatling2 REPL console?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop, gatling

I would like to use a scala REPL console for Gatling to debug some code and evaluate it.
Is there any easy way to do that? Is there a fast way to do a syntax check on Gatling scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SBT, you can always take advantage of SBT's console task to get Gatling in your classpath and and experiment with its APIs, but you won't be able to execute requests, etc... from the REPL.

The next best solution is to use Gatling's SBT plugin (https://github.com/gatling/gatling-sbt) : using it, you can quickly compile and run your simulations, even launch them on every successful compilation until the result suits you.

Comment: Thank you. The testQuick is much faster than the maven plugin for checking the code. I will explore what I can do with the scala console. I suppose there is a way to write simple tests totally in scala using then underlying libs, there should be some unit test cases for gatling itself. Any experience with running gatling itself in a debugger?

Comment: TBH, no, never ran Gatling in a debugger.